# How to support extra color options for shortcodes?

Tags: customization, shortcode, css

I'm creating a WordPress theme and it's almost complete. I've created few shortcodes for some of the elements, including buttons with different color options like blue, green, red etc. What I want now is to allow users to be able to provide their own color hex value if they don't like the provided color options, like this for example:

```
[button color="#123423"]Button Text[/button].
```

Now I also know how I would get the value in the backend, but I just can't figure out how I will provide support for this in my CSS. For instance, I've got something like this:

```
.button-blue{
    background: blue;
}
.button-green{
    background: green;
}
```

Now how can insert the user provided button color for that specific button?

Comment: First: why are you adding post-content shortcodes to a Theme? Second: please **edit your question** to include your shortcode callback; without seeing your actual code, there's no way to help answer your question specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options.

---

A) Use inline-CSS:

```
<button style="background: <?php echo CHOSEN_COLOR_HERE (possibly validated) ?>;">
    ...
</button>
```

---

B) Write (ID-specific) CSS styles into your page. In your shortcode function, echo a `<style>` tag, for instance like so:

```
<style>
#shortcode-button-1 {
    background: <?php echo CHOSEN_COLOR_HERE (possibly validated) ?>;
}

#shortcode-button-2 {
    background: <?php echo CHOSEN_COLOR_HERE (possibly validated) ?>;
}
</style>
```

For this method, you need to *track* your shortcode buttons, meaning: give them some unique ID that you use to target the buttons.

---

C) Use a dynamic style sheet (i.e., a `shortcode-styles.php` file that acts as a CSS file).

For this method, you need to *register* your shortcode buttons (e.g., in some global variable, a transient, an option etc.). Then, using some *late-running* hook (e.g., `wp_footer`, `wp_print_footer_scripts` etc.) you enqueue the php/CSS file, which could look something like the following:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
// Suppose you are using a global variable for your shortcode buttons
global $shortcode_buttons;
foreach ($shortcode_buttons as $id => $color) {
    ?>
    #shortcode-button-<?php echo $id; ?> {
        background: <?php echo $color; // maybe validate ?>;
    }
    <?php
}
?>
```

---

**Note:** I did not test any of this, however, I hope you get the idea(s).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I understood the first option, but I'm sure it's not the best method of the rest. For the second, is this the one where you use a php file to act as a css file? And for the third option, I think it is the best one as I've heard it is the best way to do it; however, is it done by using wp_add_inline_style function? which adds css to an existing stylesheet? i'm still reading about this.